# How to avoid showing multiple row? Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    `BillNum` 
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( `City` , ' / ' , `Region` , ' / ' , `StreetName` , ' / ' , `Closepoint`)) AS 'Address' 
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', `ItemCount` ,')', `ItemName` , ' ' )separator ' ') AS OrderInfo 
    , CustomerPhone , `OrderTime` 
FROM orderin 
INNER JOIN `customers` 
WHERE `CustomerPhone` = `customers`.`PhoneNumber` 
    AND `TableNum` = '0' AND DeleveryState = '0' 
GROUP BY `BillNum` 
ORDER BY `BillNum`;
```

Where is this wrong ? Why the address is multiplied ?

[image]

Comment: can you show the columns of your tables?

use a unique column for your customer like customerId.

perhaps you have 2 customers in your customers table with phone number 1234:

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE '1234' = `customers`.`PhoneNumber` AND `TableNum` = '0' AND DeleveryState = '0'

Comment: You need to add more code to have a good answer for you problem. The query you post is probably not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Add Distinct to your Group_Concat

Like

```
SELECT 
  `BillNum` 
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( `City` , ' / ' , `Region` , ' / ' , `StreetName` , ' / ' , `Closepoint`)) AS 'Address' 
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('(', `ItemCount` ,')', `ItemName` , ' ' )separator ' ') AS OrderInfo 
  , CustomerPhone , `OrderTime` 
FROM orderin INNER JOIN `customers` 
WHERE `CustomerPhone` = `customers`.`PhoneNumber` 
      AND `TableNum` = '0' AND DeleveryState = '0' 
GROUP BY `BillNum` 
ORDER BY `BillNum`
```

Comment: It's worked. thank you. but u didn't answer (bill number , phone num  i get 1 result only Note that it's more than row.  but address is multiplied  in result?)

Comment: I took your omage and it shows two identical addresses, so one can be eliminated by using Distinct, if you have further problems add on dbfddle the data and we address it.

Comment: Your inner join  has no on clause you should check that